# Сворачивание, разворачивание блока jQuery.

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

```
    $("#proj_inf_more").click(function() {
    $("#proj_inf").css('height', 'auto');
    $("#proj_inf_more").delay(500).toggleClass("ar_act");
    return false;
});
```

Всем привет. Есть блок #proj_inf. у него высота 93px. Нужно при клике на #proj_inf_more менять высоту на auto, при повторном снова на 93px. В коде выше я сделал разворачивание блока, а как обратно свернуть, не знаю. Поомогите плиз.

P.S. Разворачивание можно сделать плавно? Я пытался animate использовать, но не получилось..

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: http://www.sooource.net/jquery-collapsable-blocks

Comment: этот вариант скрывает и раскрывает весь блок. мне нужно уменьшать до 93 пикс по высоте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, animate() с параметром "auto" не работает, но можно сделать [таким способом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/nmqD4/).

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде работает)